# How to subtract overall cost whenever the count is decremented in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

My webpage has a counter for counting adult tickets ($25 each) and minor tickets ($10 each). Each counter has two buttons, one that increments the counter by 1 and another that decrements by 1. These are then stored in a list (`adultTickets` and `minorTickets`)I'm trying to make functions that can count the overall cost (e.g., 2 adult tickets and 1 minor ticket would cost $60), but I'm having problems how to track the cost for when tickets decrease, thus decreasing the price.

Here's what I have at the moment for tracking the cost, I've stripped it back to what I had originally because every fix I tried to make seemed to make it worse:

```
const countCostAdd = () => {
       let overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) + (minorTickets.length * 10);
       setCost(overallCost);
    };

    const countCostMinus = () => {
        let overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) - (minorTickets.length * 10);
        setCost(overallCost);
    }
```

The add part works perfect, but the minus function doesn't. For example, the user adds 2 minor tickets, but then takes away 1. The overall cost should be 10, but its coming out as -10 because ((0 x 25 = 0) - (1 x 10)). I've tried capping it at 0, but that created an issue that whenever adultTickets.length = 0, it would make the whole overall cost 0 even if there were tickets selected.

Comment: You don’t need the subtraction operation. The addition operation should be used any time you need to update the cost.

Comment: Why would you ever subtract? Your logic makes no sense. Also, better to put this kind of side effect in its own useEffect or useMemo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
const countCostMinus = () => {
    if(overallCost != 0) {
        let overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) + (minorTickets.length * 10);
        setCost(overallCost);
    }}
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, its because my script didn't actually save the overallCost everytime it was updated, so nothing needed to be subtracted from it. Everytime I decrement by 1, the length of the array changes automatically, so it just needs to do the same thing that the countCostAdd does.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you're taking away tickets, what you're doing is subtracting the number of minor tickets from the number of adult tickets. So what the function is doing is totally resetting the overallCost with 0 - 20, changing it to 0 - 10 when you decrement, and that's what you're getting.

So to decrement adult tickets it should be overallCost = ((adultTickets.length - 1) * 25) + (minorTickets.length * 10). And to decrement minor tickets, it should be overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) + (minorTickets.length - 1 * 10). You probably need separate functions because of the different values. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try using backticks to wrap the code you may use on your answer, it looks cleaner and easier to read, like`this`